# How to fix array numbering bug in .map

Tags: javascript

I have difficulty setting correct numbering in .map method. I have a drag and drop functionality and if I drag new item above the default text, everything is working right and numbering starts from 1, however if i drop it under - numbering starts from 2.

I've tried resetting index inside first if statement of else, however it did not work.

```
 setTable(rows, id) {
  if (rows.length === 0) {
    const table = document.getElementById(id)
    const row = table.insertRow(0);
    const cell = row.insertCell(0);

    if (component === 'test') {
      cell.innerHTML = "No tests are available.";
    } 
  } else {
    [...rows].map((row, index) => {
      if (row.getAttribute('data-name') === null && rows.length !== 
1) {
        row.remove()
        return row
      }

      // changing the numbers inside the <Number /> tag
      if (id === 'your-tests') {
        row.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerText = `${index + 1}.`
      } else {
        row.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerText = ""
      }
    })
  }
}
```

So I get correct numbering starting from 1, if I drop item above "No tests are available.", but numbering starts from 2, if I drop under.

Comment: It's pretty hard to help you with just this code. How is `setTable` called? What drag & drop are you talking about? What "numbering" are you referring to, the `index` part of `Array.map`? etc.

Comment: The whole question is about index. It needs to be reset to 0, if first element is default text and is removed with row.remove()